# Erron on ch() function

Tags: javascript

Error when I click in td. Why?

```js
function ch() {
  console.log("cliked")
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick='ch()'>
      click on td
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div onclick="ch()">click on div</div>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't show an error. EDIT: oops, oh, yes it does.

Comment: @AKX It is showing an error just click on "click on td".

Comment: Right you are – `typeof ch` shows `string` there... 

Comment: I would assume it's some kind of scoping issue with a keyword/property interefering with the HTMLTableCellElement. This is yet another reason to ***never*** use inline event handlers. Change the logic to use `addEventListener()` instead

Comment: Is not a dublicate question. "clear" is reserved word, "ch" - not!

Comment: @Vitalicus that's not true. Neither are "reserved words", both are something that exists in scope of the inline event handler when the developer didn't expect it or didn't think about it. The cause is the same for your question as is for all three linked questions.

Comment: @Vitalicus `clear` is not a reserved word. Yes, it's a duplicate because the core of the issue is that the name resolution would pick the attribute of the DOM node over the global function. If you really think it's *not* a duplicate, you must also mean that ***EVERY SINGLE COMBINATION*** of an inline event handler and a DOM node property is a unique distinct question to ask about. If so, feel free to start asking about each one in alphabetical or whatever you want order. Or do you think that "using a node's property in an inline event handler uses the property" answers all of them?

Answer (score 8):

Quoth [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement#htmltablecellelement.ch):

> **HTMLTableCellElement.ch** (Deprecated)
>
> A string containing one single character. This character is the one to align all the cell of a column on. It reflects the [`char`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#char) and default to the decimal points associated with the language, e.g. '.' for English, or ',' for French. This property was optional and was not very well supported.

In other words, when in an inline event handler for a table cell element, you end up trying to call a string as a function.

The fix is to name `ch()` something else (or to refer to it as e.g. `window.ch()` if you can't rename it).

Comment: "The fix is to name ch() something else" - just note that this may still only be a temporary fix as tomorrow a new property may be introduced to `HTMLTableCellElement`s which may yet again clash with the name of your function.

Comment: @CherryDT Theoretically yes, but considering how cautious the Web API folks had been in adding e.g. `Array#flat()` with that name and not `flatten()` because the semantics were not the same as (IIRC) a MooTools function by the same name, I don't think it's a big risk. But using `window.ch()`, or better yet a non-inline handler would be better, nonetheless.

Comment: "The fix is to name ch() something else..." *that is not a reserved word or in-scope property*